# Calling Activity methods from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use a fragment only inside one specific parent activity. Now I wonder if there are any drawbacks if I call methods in the parent activity directly from the included fragment like this:

> getActivity().someMethodInParentActivitiy()

A more common solution would be to define a formal listener interface in the fragment to call back to the parent activity and then make the activity implement that interface.

Are there any reasons (e.g. *reliability* or *speed*) why I should use the second more complex solution instead of direct method calls from the fragment to the activity?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't look at the performance at the begining. Remember "premature optimization is the root of all evil". The second approach is better because your fragment could be used in different activities. The first approach introduces more dependencies in your code, the fragment is dependent to the activity type. You're loosing ability to test, reuse, small complex. It may seem to be simpler right now, but in the future you'll see ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I also notice that accessing the activity method directly through getActivity() is not so easy. Probably I need an additional cast?

Comment: Yep, to the implementation that contains `someMethodInParentActivitiy()`. But as I wrote it's not recommended.

Comment: Actually I got a bit confused, because Diane Hackborn states that using such method calls is ok:
http://markmail.org/thread/sgvnc7bjtjfbh5rx#query:+page:1+mid:6kakhwquxdigf7om+state:results

Comment: She also wrote about more formal solution ;)

Answer (score 25):

Additional cast need to be done:

```
Activity activity123 = getActivity();

if(activity123 instanceof ParentActivity) {
    ((ParentActivity) activity123).someMethodInParentActivity();
}
```

however as @pawelzieba wrote if u want to use that fragment in another activities which is probably the case it will not work this way.. Cheers

Answer (score 9):

When I need to do something like this, I just use a BroadcastReceiver so I can call it from anywhere.

> ```
> BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         String action = intent.getAction();
>         if (action != null) {
>             if (action.equals("WHATEVER_ACTION")) {
>                 // Do stuff
>             }
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

Then in my fragment I will just use:

> activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("WHATEVER_ACTION"));

Comment: Looks like best practice to me. A basic design pattern, too.

Comment: Do we have to register the broadcaster in manifest too to use it just for communication between activity and fragment?