# Execute public Method of Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, methods, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a Fragment, which should execute a (public) Method `reset()` from the Activity in the Fragment it is called from.

I found, for example, this page: 
[Calling Activity methods from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212574/calling-activity-methods-from-fragment) 
The other way there's no problem:

```
Input_tap Input_tap = (Input_tap) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.input);
Input_tap.reset();
```

Does someone has any idea how to do it the other way?
and: Does the Method has to be public - its a "void" Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Fragment` can call `getActivity()` to retrieve the activity that is hosting it.

If there is only one possible activity that can host the fragment, just cast the `Activity` to the proper class (e.g., `MyActivity`) and call a method on it:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).someMethod();
```

If there might be more than one activity that can host the fragment, you are best served by implementing a common `interface` on all those activities, so you can cast `getActivity()`'s result to that interface:

```
((MyInterface)getActivity()).someMethod();
```